# CALayer -renderInContext: is unreasonably slow with transform

Tags: ios, transform, calayer, quartz-graphics

A `UIView`'s `CALayer` takes 0.002 seconds on iPhone 5 to render itself into a 60x60pt context using `-renderInContext:`.

However, **It takes 0.07 seconds as soon as rotation or scale is applied to its transform**.

That is 35x slower, leading me to believe there is something terribly wrong.
Translation alone does not affect performance, only rotation and scale. 
My UIView renders a large (1024x768pt) image in its `-drawRect:` method, but image itself is not the main issue (also drawRect is not called by renderInContext, it must be doing its own thing). Opacity of the view (`-isOpaque`) has no noticeable effect on performance.

I don't understand why the transform is adversely affecting performance. How can I fix it?